# spy on mocked object accessor (get and set)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, stub

Mocking out dependencies while testing angular components. ComponentA injects ServiceA, I want to mock serviceA in my test

```
class ServiceA {
    private _prop = 1;

    get prop (): number {
        return this._prop;
    }

    set prop(p: number) {
        this._prop;
    }
}

class ComponentA {
    private injectedService: ServiceA;

    constructor(private injectedService: ServiceA) {
        this.injectedService = injectedService;
    }

    method () {
        this.injectedService.prop = this.injectedService.prop + 1;
        if (this.injectedService.prop === 5) {
            this.injectedService.prop = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

With the above program structure it is important to have a serviceA mock that has accessor(getter and setter for injectedService.prop) implementation, since a part of the program is dependent on the value of injectedService.prop that was prior set.

Options that I have tried:

[**ts-mockito:**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mockito) ts-mockito mocks *does not have access type set*. With this limitation ts setter won't be recognised. A workaround would be to define actual methods to 'set' and 'get' and call these methods. setter would still need a more workaround as below:

```
// default get stub
when(mock.getProp()).thenReturn();

// setter redefines get stub
when(mock.setProp(anything())).thenCall((p) => {
    when(mock.getProp()).thenReturn(a);
});
```

[**typemoq:**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typemoq)

- [static mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typemoq#static-mocks) calls constructor, big flaw when target mock class as other dependency injection(s)
- [dynamic mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typemoq#dynamic-mocks) conditions like (this.injectedService.prop === 5) will never be truthy beacuse this.injectedService.prop (i.e mock.object.prop) points to a function. On this I feel there could be a way that I'm yet to figure out, I would appreciate any help
- (Personal preference) I prefer jasmine [spyOn](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to typemoq [verify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typemoq#verify-expectations-one-by-one) for assertions on my mocks. This could be ignored if not possible.

**Things I don't want to do**

- I do not want to modify classes to be mocked except to add standard typescript accessors
- I do not want to create an Interface/Class off classes to be mocked just for the purpose of creating a mock for test

*Although I'm open to compromise on above if there is a good justification or standard*

I would also appreciate if anybody could direct me to code base(s) that has proper test and follows standard *if any*.

Note: I'm testing an angular app with karma + jasmine ... but all these doesn't count as I am merely creating class from constructor, no Testbed just simple typescript class unit-test.